# LIBNAME error on MSAccess database import

Tags: sas

I am trying to import a MSAccess database and it's not working. I am running Windows 7 64 bit. My MS Office software is 2010. My SAS is 9.4 for 64 bit. Therefore, every piece of documentation I have found which talks about version incompatibility and offers a solution is NOT WORKING.

Here is what I've done:

```
1    PROC IMPORT TABLE = "Trends" DBMS = ACCESS OUT = WORK.SASTrends     
REPLACE;
2    DATABASE = "C:\Users\bennetde\Documents\Trends in Early Onset 
study\Trends in Early Onset
2  ! (clean).accdb";
3    RUN;

ERROR: Connect: Class not registered
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.
Connection Failed.  See log for details.
NOTE: The SAS System stopped processing this step because of errors.
NOTE: PROCEDURE IMPORT used (Total process time):
  real time           0.73 seconds
  cpu time            0.07 seconds
```

And:

```
4    LIBNAME libref ACCESS PATH = "C:\Users\bennetde\Documents\Trends in     
Early Onset
4  ! study\Trends in Early Onset (clean).accdb";
ERROR: Connect: Class not registered
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement
```

Please help me solve this problem so I can import my MSAccess database. Thank you.

Comment: Is your Office installation 32bit?

Comment: It was!!! And as soon as I switched it to 64 bit, the problem was solved. Hallelujah!

Answer (score -1):

I solved my own problem. My version of MS Office was 32 bit instead of 64 bit, which wasn't compatible for imports.